# how i can open different linux terminal to output differnt kinds of debug information in python?

Tags: python, terminal, stream

I need output different information to different terminal instances instead of print them in same output stream, say std.err or std.out.

for example:
I have 5 kinds of information say A-E need to be displayed on different terminal windows on same desktop, looks like

[terminal 1]  <- for displaying information A

[terminal 2]  <- for displaying information B

[terminal 3]  <- for displaying information C

[terminal 4]  <- for displaying information D

[terminal 5]  <- for displaying information E

I know I can output them into different files, then open terminals read the file in loop,
but what I want is python program can open terminal by program itself and print to them directly when it is needed.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

KC

[edit]
the best solution for this case is using SOCKET as the IPC I think if the resource is not a matter, it will come with best compatible capability - a server client mode.
and the pipe / subprocess will also be the useful solutions under same platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a pipe, then fork off a terminal running `cat` reading from the read end of the pipe, and write into the write end of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, just run several instances of whichever terminal program you like, each running "cat", using subprocess.Popen. Pass stdin=subprocess.PIPE in addition to the terminal command to Popen. Then you can just write to each terminal's stdin attribute.

Something along the lines of (untested!):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('xterm -e "cat > /dev/null"', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write("Hello World!")
```

Comment: thanks!
the original line seems missing parameter "shell=True," otherwise it will goes exceptional. 
however, after I added the shell=True, is shows nothing on the xterm... 


import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('xterm -e "cat > /dev/null"', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

p.stdin.write("Hello World!")

Comment: Perhaps this is because of buffering? Try p.stdin.flush() after writing to it. I'm sorry but I don't have access to a Linux terminal at the moment to try this out.