# Python: How to execute a thread in a new terminal window/command prompt?

Tags: python, multithreading, terminal

How to execute a thread in a script in a new terminal window/command prompt? So that the results of the thread will be displayed on a separate window while still having control on the main interpreter? The thread is a continuous remote server pinging thread for alive check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how i can open different linux terminal to output differnt kinds of debug information in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933601/how-i-can-open-different-linux-terminal-to-output-differnt-kinds-of-debug-informa)

Comment: well, had a look at it earlier but it seems like its more of shell commands. my case would more on threading on windows.

Answer (score 0):

The `-S` option of `xterm` can be used to pass a PTY slave file descriptor. Data written to the corresponding PTY master should then appear in the `xterm` window.

So in your thread, you could call `os.openpty()` to open a new PTY, start an `xterm` with `subprocess.Popen()`, passing a suitable `-S` option, and write all thread's output to the PTY master fd.

I tried this on Linux but couldn't get any output on the `xterm`. Googling around suggests a bug in `xterm`, as this is a rarely used feature. Or maybe you can figure out how to do it correctly :)