# Python 3.x How to run external program and execute command in new terminal tab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, macos-mojave, iterm2

who can explain and show an example how to run external program and execute command there?

I want to do this:
1)  Run a new window of the terminal
2)  Send a command to execute in the terminal

System: Mac Os

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/iTerm.app"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
test.stdin.write("ls")


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/NEWA/PycharmProjects/TEST/TEST.py", line 3, in <module>
    test.stdin.write("ls")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: `test.stdin.write(b"ls")`

Comment: Doesn't work. The command hasn't been send to the terminal.

Comment: That only fixes the specific error you had. It doesn't actually send anything to the terminal. 

I think you would need to create a unix pipe and execute everything you find in it. STDIN is something that belongs to unix commands, it's not something that iTerm has. So you can't attach to it like that. 

You can have a read at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558720/using-pythons-subprocess-to-display-output-in-new-xterm-window 
It has some more info, though it's not doing exactly what you want.

Comment: If it's something simple, like `ls`, you can do it all in one call like this:

`subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/open", "-W", "-n", "-a", "/Applications/iTerm.app", "--args", "ls"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Comment: the same situation with --args
the terminal has been opened but nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I once used this on my Flask and Scrapy project, you have to use,

```
subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None)
```

See here https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
For more info

Answer (score -1):

I usually use os.system like this:

```
import os
os.system("<command to run>")
```

EDIT Mac OS is very inconvenient and not supported by much. I would recommend using Windows or Linux to develop as they are a lot more flexible when it comes to development. there seems to be no command on Mac that is able to run it in another window. windows is able to open a new window by doing `start cmd.exe`. I am not able to help further due to the limitations of mac os.

Comment: The OP wants to run the command **in a new terminal**. This doesn't do that at all.